# How to convert PHP mysql_fetch_array() into NSMutableArray? PHP --> Xcode

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to read an entire row from **mysql** into a `NSMutableArray` using **PHP**.

Example **PHP** Code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$db_selected = mysql_select_db("test_db",$con);
$sql = "SELECT * from Person WHERE Lastname='smith'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo(mysql_fetch_array($result));

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The output of the array above could be:

```
Array
(
[0] => smith
[LastName] => smith
[1] => Adam
[FirstName] => Adam
[2] => California
[Address] => California
[3] => 22
[Age] => 22
)
```

How do I read that array from **mysql**, and store that as a `NSMutableArray`?

So far, I only know how to receive a string from **PHP** using the following:

```
//to execute php code
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

//to receive the returned value
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I don't know how to read an array and convert that into a `NSMutableArray`. I spent hours searching and I cannot find an answer. I would prefer not to use **JSON** and stick with `Mysql/PHP/Obj-c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not so simply eheh. You have to transform the HTML data in something that iOS can understand. Of course, if you do the `var_dump()` of the $result array is not something that iOS can understand! You have to convert the string in a universal format like JSON or XML, and then download the data. So, when iOS receive the JSON/XML, you can handle it using reflection or something else to reproduce the JSON objects.